# How to replace a simple SetTimeout and ClearTimeout with requestAnimationFrame in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, requestanimationframe, cleartimeout

Here is my code block using **setTimeout** and **clearTimeout** which I want to replace with **requestAnimationFrame** -

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [copyText, setCopyText] = useState("Copy");
  const copyTextHandler = () => {
    setCopyText("Copied");
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setCopyText("copy");
    }, 3000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  };
  
  return (<button onClick={copyTextHandler} disabled={copyTextHandler === "Copied"}>{copyText}</button>)
}
```

I tried searching for a few solutions in stack overflow and other platforms but couldn't find a fix for it.

Comment: Did you try replacing `setTimeout` with `requestAnimationFrame` and replacing `clearTimeout` with `cancelAnimationFrame`?

Comment: Yes, replacing it also didn't work for me. Also parameters are different so we can't directly replace them.

Comment: Replacing the method calls and removing the unused `3000` parameter [does what I'd expect](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-tree-3h1cwu?file=/src/App.js). Perhaps you could elaborate on what you expect to happen / what "didn't work"?

Comment: Yes this is the solution I tried, maybe you can guide me more about the syntax. I'm facing the problem with replacement itself.

Comment: The sandbox [that I linked to](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-tree-3h1cwu?file=/src/App.js) contains the code I was suggesting

Comment: It didn't go back to "Copying" after 3 or more seconds. I wanted to show the Copied text temporarily but then again go back to previous text "Copy" after 3 seconds.

Comment: That's what your existing code does. You do not need to use `requestAnimationFrame` to achieve what you are already doing – `setTimeout` is the appropriate method.

Comment: I do, but I am trying to implement same thing using requestAnimationFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you shouldn't, because `setTimeout` is the way to do this".

However, if you absolutely have to use `requestAnimationFrame` then you can use it to repeatedly check if it's time to change the text.

You could do this by passing a time at which the text should change back:

```js
  const changeTextChecker = (time) => {
    if (Date.now() > time) {
      setCopyText("copy");
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => changeTextChecker(time));
    }
  };
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-worker-dlq3bg?file=/src/App.js)

But I prefer to set a timeout to set a flag that indicates that the time has passed, because this is more in keeping with the thinking behind this task:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const changeTextChecker = () => {
      if (shouldChangeText.current) {
        setCopyText("copy");
        shouldChangeText.current = false; // reset for next time
      } else requestAnimationFrame(changeTextChecker);
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(changeTextChecker);
  }, []);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-babbage-39bryd?file=/src/App.js)

In both cases you are circumventing Javascript's asynchronous event queue by polling rather than just using the appropriate tool for the task. However, it does *exactly* answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation about why using it is not a good option.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure requestAnimationFrame is a bad choice. For instance, if you are polling an api, BUT the person is not even on the webpage (its in the foreground), or is on another tab - imagine the amount of resources used... that aren't needed. Especially if they keep ur tab open days w/o looking at it?

Comment: @jamesemanon Of course requestAnimationFrame has its proper uses, but the question here is about emulating a timed delay with animationframe-based polling, which is somewhat absurd.